# How to implement a RESTful Web Server supporting HTTPS with C++?

Tags: c++, linux, web-services, rest, https

Microsoft has [C++ REST SDK](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/) project for cloud-based client-server communication, nevertheless the server end doesn't support HTTPS yet.
What are the key points if I want to implement this with C++.

Comment: Perhaps this question is too broad-- are you trying to extend the sdk?

Comment: Use a library like [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) to do your reading and writing. Otherwise its a normal `HTTP` session.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you ask. you may consider tunnel the HTTPS with `nginx` or `stud`, and use your plain HTTP server as upstream.